# how to concat a value of a specific tag where other tag = 'E' using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml that looks like this :

```
<TransmissionReport>
    <IntegrationLogMessage>
        <code>E</code>
        <msg>msg1</msg>
    </IntegrationLogMessage>
    <IntegrationLogMessage>
        <code>S</code>
        <msg>msg2</msg>
    </IntegrationLogMessage>
    <IntegrationLogMessage>
        <code>E</code>
        <msg>msg3</msg>
    </IntegrationLogMessage>
</TransmissionReport>
```

what  i want to do is to concat all msg nodes , where code = E
so the output should look like :

```
 msg1,msg3
```

what is the easiest way to achive that with XSLT transformation ?

Comment: Which XSLT version and engine are you using? What have you tried? This is really simple.

Comment: This is a trivial problem - esp. if you can use XSLT 2.0 or higher. Where exactly are you stuck with this?